# can't understand for nested loop

Tags: nested-for-loop

I am new to programming, I ran into this pattern problem which I am confused of the solution.

Output:

1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5

Input(correct solution):

```
rows = 6

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print('')
```

What I think the process of the code will be like:

In 1st iteration - i is 0; j is 0; print i; therefore, 0 is printed

In 2nd iteration - i is 1; j is 0, 1; the action is to print i; therefore, 1 is printed

In 3rd iteration - i is 2; j is 0, 1,2; the action is to print i; therefore, 2 is printed

I am sure my idea is wrong but can anyone point out what is wrong and correct me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

welcome!

```py
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(i):
```

The first time through, `i` is `0`, so `for j in range(i):` runs zero times.

The second time, `i` is `1`, so `for j in range(i)` prints `1` 1 time.

The third time, `i` is `2`, so `for j in range(i)` prints `2` 2 times… and so on.

Answer (score 1):

well, i is the iteration for changing the number (0 to 5), j is the iteration for repeating this number "i" times. so:

In 1st iteration - i is 0; j is 0; 0 is printed 0 times (none)

In 2nd iteration - i is 1; j is 0-1; prints 1 one time

In 3rd iteration - i is 2; j is 0-2; prints 2 two times

In 4th iteration - i is 3; j is 0-3; prints 3 three times